# Fit model to density function by regression: improvements?

Tags: r

I try to fit a model to the density function by regression to get a parameter estimation.

It seems to work well but the parameter estimations from the `nlxb` function producing no good values and so the predicted model in comparison to the kernel densities is quite bad.

Maybe somebody knows how can I improve the parameter estimation by regression?

Here is my code:

```
   x<-c(4853,4214,5803,3430,4645,4485,3100,4797,4030,3590,5396,9864,3683,4485,4064,3420,5396,
          4895,3931,4238,3790,3520,4263,5474,3790,4700,5109,4525,4007,6340,4993,6903,8160,3600,3480,3540,3540,4565,3333,7764,  
          4755,7940,3112,3169,4435,5365,9422,3150,10500,4512,3790,4618,6126,3769,3704,
         5938,5669,4552,5458,5854,4867,6057,4783,5753,5736,4618,6091,5820,5007,7984, 4435,
         4645,7465,5820,5988,6022,4300,6062,3302,4877,4586,5275,4410,3174,4966,4939,4638,
         5541,5760,6495,5435,4952,4912,6092,5182,5820,5129,6436,6648,3063,5550,5160,4400,
         9600,6400,6380,6300,6180,6899,4360,5550,4580,3894,5277,7520,6780,5100,5430,4550,
         6620,4050,4560,5290,6610,8560,4943,6940,4744,6650,5700,7440,6200,4597,3697,7300,
         4644,5456,6302,3741,5398,9500,6296,5279,5923,6412,6559,6559,5891,5737,5010,5790,
         10300,4150,4870,6740,7560,8010,5120,8170,7430, 7330,5900, 11150)


     p<-density(x,n=163, from = 3000, to=11150)
     s<-p$y
     t<-p$x

     fitsim <- nlxb(s ~ ((k*((g-x)^(k-1)))*(g-a)/((v^k)*((x-a)^(k+1))))*(exp(-(((g-x)/(v*(x-a)))^k))), 
           data = data.frame(s, t),
           start = list(g= 14000,a = 3000 , v=1 , k = 1))
    fitsim

    fit.nls <- nls2(s~((k*((g-x)^(k-1)))*(g-a)/((v^k)*((x- a)^(k+1))))*(exp(-(((g-x)/(v*(x-a)))^k))), 
            data = x, 
            start = fitsim$coefficients,
            algorithm = "brute-force")
    fit.nls

   p<-predict(fit.nls,data.frame(x=x))
   hist(x,freq = FALSE)
   lines(density(x,from=3000,to=11150),col="green")
   points(p~x)
```

Comment: This is not a technical or programming question; you should have more success in cross-validated stack community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need better starting values.

```
library(nlmrt)
library(nls2)

den <- density(x,n=163, from = 3000, to=11150)
fo <- y ~ ((k*((g-x)^(k-1)))*(g-a)/((v^k)*((x-a)^(k+1))))*(exp(-(((g-x)/(v*(x-a)))^k)))

# use nls2 to get starting values on a grid bounded by 0.1 * st1 and 10 * st1
st1 <- c(g = 14000, a = 3000, v = 1, k = 1) # starting values from question
st2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(0.1 * st1, 10 * st1))
fit.nls2 <- nls2(fo, den[1:2], start = st2, alg = "brute")

# fit with nlxb and then use nls2 to get an nls object
fit.nlxb <- nlxb(fo, data = den[1:2], start = coef(fit.nls2))
fit.nlxb.nls <- nls2(fo, data = den[1:2], start = fit.nlxb$coef, alg = "brute")

plot(den[1:2], type = "l")
lines(fitted(fit.nlxb.nls) ~ x, den[1:2], col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]